# Map with ggplot2 and bubbles

Tags: r, maps, ggplot2

[image]

I've tried to plot a map of magnitude earthquakes in Colombia with `ggplot`. After many efforts, I got it. But, I need to focus in specially area where the data of magnitudes is (4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5). When I use the same script for this data, I get this:

> "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale".

I've used many solutions in blogs but it does not work.

This is my first map and the script

```
santos <- readOGR("Departamentos_WGS84.shp","Departamentos_WGS84")
map <- fortify(santos)
datos=read.table("coord.txt",header=T,dec=",",sep=";")
myData = data.frame(datos)

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=map, map=map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id, group=group),
                    fill="#fffcfc", color="#0e0e0e", size=0.15) + 
                    geom_point(data=myData, 
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, size=Magnitud), color = "red",shape = 21) +
                    scale_size(range = c(0, 8)) + 
                    coord_map() + 
                    theme_bw() + 
                    labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) + 
                    theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) + 
                    theme(panel.border=element_rect())
                    gg
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. My data are coordinates (longitude and latitutde) associated with a magnitude. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: what is the output of this command `class(myData$Magnitud)`? `factor` or `numeric` (this could be the source of your error)

Comment: I guess `myData$long` and/or `myData$lat` are character values ("discrete"), because the `read.table` does not work as expected. And that does not match with `map$long`, which is numeric. Maybe you can add the output of `str(map)` and `str(myData)`.

Comment: Excuse me! With class(myData$Magnitud), I got "factor".

Comment: this should be `numeric`

Comment: Excuse me! But I changed the class of "myData$Magnitud" to  numeric and I got the same Error.

Comment: As I said: What's with `myData$lat` and `myData$lon`?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with these instructions:

```
myData$longitude = as.numeric(as.character(myData$longitude))

myData$Magnitude = as.numeric(as.character(myData$Magnitude))

myData$latitude = as.numeric(as.character(myData$latitude))
```